# Media query to filter css rules based on current month

Tags: css

We often get the task of changing backgrounds for certain seasons.

Do anyone know if something like creating a `@media` query based on month is possible or will become possible?

Like this

```
@media(min-month:11) and (max-month:1)
{
  body
  {
    background: url("snowy.png") center top;
    background-size: cover;
  }
}
```

Comment: I think creating separate css files and load them based on current month is the way to go. This needs some server side logic to render the `<link>` tag dynamically. With this, you can extend with more styles depending on current month easily.

Comment: No, CSS cannot detect your month, but you can add dynamic classes to the element via JavaScript and style them with CSS.

Comment: I would go for adding a class to the body tag server side. However, I am still interested in how to do it with pure css, now or in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Date and time information is unlikely to ever be supported as a media query. Media queries are intended to apply conditional styling based on properties of the output device (or "medium"), such as device width, or whether the content is being printed. The supported types can be found in the [W3C documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/#background), and should give you a sense of the intent behind media queries.

Logic on either the server side (to render the document with a reference to the appropriate stylesheet, perhaps) or client (possibly by adding the appropriate classes via JavaScript) would likely be necessary to accomplish conditional styles based on dates.

Comment: I would agree using `@media` rules would be illogical. Adding a `@date`rule would be appropriate. I still consider how the webpage should look in the summer etc as part of the style.

Comment: @AndersLindén That could be true, and maybe `@date` will be added in the future, but it would be a new feature rather than a media query.